# Доступ к полям с повторяющимися названиями

Tags: sql, delphi, sqlite, delphi-7

В следующей процедуре с помощью стандартного компонента подключения к базам данных SQLite в Delphi XE3 я выполняю sql-запрос к базе данных, содержащий поля с одинаковыми названиями из разных таблиц. Затем я обращаюсь к этим полям через алиас

```
procedure CreationListOfFields(SQLConn: TSQLConnection; DBSchema : TDBSchemaSpec);
var
  NameField : TField;
  PositionField : TField;
  DescriptionField : TField;
  CanInputField : TField;
  CanEditField : TField;
  ShowInGridField : TField;
  ShowInDetailsField : TField;
  IsMeanField : TField;
  AutocalculatedField : TField;
  RequiredField : TField;
  Name1 : TField;
  Name2 : TField;
begin
    SQLConn.Execute('select f.id, f.position, f.name, f.description, f.can_input, '
    +' f.can_edit, f.show_in_grid, f.show_in_details, f.is_mean, f.autocalculated, f.required, tables.name tablename, domains.name domainname'
    +' from fields f left join tables on f.table_id=tables.id '
    +' left join domains on f.domain_id=domains.id order by tables.name, domains.name ', nil, results);
    if not results.IsEmpty then
      begin
        results.First;
        Name1:=results.FieldByName('tablename');
        Name2:=results.FieldByName('domainname');
        lastTable:=Name1.AsString;
        TableSpec:=TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(lastTable));
        lastDomain:=Name2.AsString;
        DomainSpec:=TDomainSpec(DBSchema.Domains.FindComponent(lastDomain));
        NameField:=results.FieldByName('name');
        PositionField:=results.FieldByName('position');
        DescriptionField:=results.FieldByName('description');
        CanInputField:=results.FieldByName('can_input');
        CanEditField:=results.FieldByName('can_edit');
        ShowInGridField:=results.FieldByName('show_in_grid');
        ShowInDetailsField:=results.FieldByName('show_in_details');
        IsMeanField:=results.FieldByName('is_mean');
        AutocalculatedField:=results.FieldByName('autocalculated');
        RequiredField:=results.FieldByName('required');
        while not results.Eof do
          begin
            if (Name1.AsString<>lastTable) then
            begin
              lastTable:=Name1.AsString;
              TableSpec:=TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(lastTable));
            end;
            if (Name2.AsString<>lastDomain) then
            begin
              lastDomain:=Name2.AsString;
              DomainSpec:=TDomainSpec(DBSchema.Domains.FindComponent(lastDomain));
            end;
            FieldSpec:=TFieldSpec.Create(TableSpec.Fields);
            FieldSpec.Setup( DomainSpec, PositionField.AsInteger,
            NameField.AsString, DescriptionField.AsString,
            FieldToBoolean(CanInputField),FieldToBoolean(CanEditField),
            FieldToBoolean(ShowInGridField), FieldToBoolean(ShowInDetailsField),
            FieldToBoolean(IsMeanField),FieldToBoolean(AutocalculatedField),
            FieldToBoolean(RequiredField));
            TComponent(FieldSpec).Name:=NameField.AsString;
            TableSpec.Fields.InsertComponent(FieldSpec);
            results.Next;
          end;
      end;
end;
```

Но при вызове этой процедуры в результате получаю сообщение `Field 'tablename' not found`. Как обратиться к полям с повторяющимися названиями, чтобы не было проблем? (варианты 'name_1' и 'name_2' не подходят, при отладке я обнаружил, что соответствующие значения пустые и как следствие из-за этого у меня возник вопрос на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/177512/delphi-access-violation-at-address-00822135-in-module-gui-exe-read-of-address-00000040 ). Использую компонент подключения к базе данных в Delphi XE3, указанный здесь - http://www.webdelphi.ru/2012/10/sqlite-v-delphi-xe3/ ).

Comment: Через точечную нотацию. Добавляй имя таблицы перед именем колонки. Например таблица products и таблица catalogs. И там и там есть колонка name. Делаем выборку: SELECT `products.name` AS first_name, `catalogs.name` AS second_name FROM `products`, `catalogs`;

Comment: Поскольку комментарии больше недоступны - пишу в ответе. @Чад количество записей больше нуля, поскольку при отладке отладчик заходит после строки 

    if not results.Empty then
`resuts.Open` не помог - да и в других случаях в аналогичных процедурах работало без него. И еще хочу сказать, что я выполнил запрос в самом sqlite - он нормально отработал.

Comment: Ну могу ещё предложить посмотреть в дебагере что за поля вообще есть в results. Может он их только по порядку метит а не по именам.

Comment: Ну так если SQL нормально отрбаотал, то где нужно искать проблему?

Comment: @Чад а что вы имели ввиду под обернуть текущий запрос select * from (запрос)? Можно подробнее объяснить как в таком случае действовать(я в смысле про Ваше предложение)?

Comment: @ivan3, да просто сделать обёртку в запросе:

     SQLConn.Execute('select * from (select f.id, f.position, f.name, f.description, f.can_input, '
    +' f.can_edit, f.show_in_grid, f.show_in_details, f.is_mean, f.autocalculated, f.required, tables.name tablename, domains.name domainname'
    +' from fields f left join tables on f.table_id=tables.id '
    +' left join domains on f.domain_id=domains.id order by tables.name, domains.name )', nil, results);

А что говорит дебаг? Что в results c полями то?

Comment: @Чад я пока что смотрю на метод `FieldByNumber` в свойстве `results.Fields` и изучаю информацию по индексам в `results.Fields`. А как в случае обертки затем обращаться к полям? Что будет вместо строк 

        Name1:=results.FieldByName('tablename');         
        Name2:=results.FieldByName('domainname');
?

Comment: Ничего не будет, всё тоже самое. Так а поставить брекпоинт проинспектировать то results? Там сразу и понятно всё будет... куда имена пропали...

Answer (score 1):

```
select f.id, f.position, f.name as name_1, f.description,...,tables.name as name_2 ...
```

Comment: @Чад не помогло. Правда я исользовал `as tablename` и `as domainname` (потому что при `as name_1` и `as name_2` возникает та же ошибка что и http://hashcode.ru/questions/177512/delphi-access-violation-at-address-00822135-in-module-gui-exe-read-of-address-00000040 ).

Comment: @Чад возникает та же ошибка `Field 'tablename' not found`.

Comment: А чё мы паримся там ваще не ошибка SQL :D

Comment: @GenchiK там sql - ошибка `Field 'tablename' not found`.

Comment: А что это такое в SQL запросе? tables.name tablename, domains.name domainname'

tables.name tablename <- Ошибка, омжет AS забыли? так же и с domains.

Comment: а что возвращает функция SQLConn.Execute ? По идее должна вернуть количество записей - вот есть у меня подозрение что если оно 0 - то поля не найдёт... Если > 0 надо думать

Comment: from fields f left join tables on f.table_id=tables.id и тут нормально написать. SQL неправильный.

Comment: а, кстати, попробуйте ещё сделать results.open() - может поможет.

Comment: Ещё вариант попробывать - обернуть текущий запрос в select * from (запрос)